# Database and Showing Results

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, mysql-workbench

I'm new in coding. It seems that I can't produce the result in this one. I am creating an RFID Tap Card System.

When I tap the card (with info in the database), the data will be saved (PictureBox1 will appear). But when I tried a different card that is not yet in the database, the code is not going to "Else" syntax or should I say PictureBox2 is not showing, still, Picturebox1 is appearing. What could be the other way for this? Thank you. This is the code.

```
    Private Sub txtReceived_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtReceived.TextChanged

    Dim mysql = "SELECT Schedule FROM tbl_patroninfo WHERE Schedule = @Sched"
    Dim myDate As Date = lbl_Date.Text
    myDate = Date.Today
    con = connectDB()
    con.Open()
    mycommand = New MySqlCommand(mysql, con)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader
    Dim SelectCommand As New MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("Select Fullname From tbl_patroninfo where PatronRFID = @PID", con)
    SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtReceived.Text
    Dim SelectCommand2 As New MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("select Department from tbl_patroninfo where PatronRFID = @PID", con)
    SelectCommand2.Parameters.Add("@PID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtReceived.Text

    If dr.Read = False Then
        con.Close()
        con.Open()
        lbl_Full.Text = CStr(SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar())
        lbl_Department.Text = CStr(SelectCommand2.ExecuteScalar())
        mycommand = New MySqlCommand("update tbl_patroninfo set Schedule = @Sched WHERE PatronRFID = @PID", con)
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@Sched", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = myDate
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@PID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtReceived.Text
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        PictureBox1.Visible = True
        con.Close()
    Else
        con.Close()
        con.Open()
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
        lbl_Full.Text = "RECORD NOT FOUND!"
        con.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should be receiving an error since you have not defined the parameter `@Sched` with a value to the one used in your first Select statement.

Comment: I tried to change the @Sched at the first Select Statement to lbl_Date.Text and the error is invalid Date Format "5/14/2019". How can I code it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of dr.Read you might want to try dr.HasRows() it will return false if it doesn't have anything.  dr.Read is generally used in While loops:

```
While dr.Read
   ' Do stuff on the records here.
End While
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this one. I'll update once I figure something else.

Comment: Still not working, it always goes through the If Statement, not on the "Not Found" if the data is not in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks by the way for your help @Daffas and @Charles May. I just did some not-so-cool stuff or should I say "cheat code" to make the system run. This is just for project purposes only. But on the next version of the system, I'll make the code right. I just used some labeling and catch-er text box and set it to Hide mode. Instead of using dr.HasRows (which is not working fine to me), I used the executeScalar codings and make this happen. This is my code so far:

```
    Dim SelectCommand As New MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("Select Fullname From tbl_patroninfo where PatronRFID = @PID", con)
    SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtReceived.Text
    Dim SelectCommand2 As New MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("select Department from tbl_patroninfo where PatronRFID = @PID", con)
    SelectCommand2.Parameters.Add("@PID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtReceived.Text
    lbl_Full.Text = txt_Catch.Text
    lbl_Full.Text = CStr(SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar())
    lbl_Department.Text = CStr(SelectCommand2.ExecuteScalar())

    If txt_Catch.Text = lbl_Full.Text Then
        con.Close()
        con.Open()
        lbl_Full.Text = "RECORD NOT FOUND!"
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
        con.Close()
        txt_Catch.Clear()

    Else
        con.Close()
        con.Open()
        '  lbl_Full.Text = CStr(SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar())
        ' lbl_Department.Text = CStr(SelectCommand2.ExecuteScalar())
        mycommand = New MySqlCommand("update tbl_patroninfo set Schedule = @Sched WHERE PatronRFID = @PID", con)
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@Sched", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = myDate
        mycommand.Parameters.Add("@PID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtReceived.Text
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(lbl_Full.Text, lbl_Time.Text)
        PictureBox1.Visible = True
        con.Close()

    End If
```